# Magento new custom block module

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm using Magento version **1.8.1.0.**

I'm trying to create a new custom block module, which I'll use for creating a new home page.

- Namespace: Crusader
- Module: CLHomePage
- Block Type: crusaderhome
- Class: Qwerty (just for now while testing)
- Design Package: crusader
- Theme: default

This is what I have so far:

\app\etc\modules\Crusader_All.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Crusader_CLHomePage>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Crusader_CLHomePage>
    </modules>
</config>
```

\app\code\local\Crusader\CLHomePage\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config> 
    <modules>
        <Crusader_CLHomePage>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Crusader_CLHomePage>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <crusaderhome>
                <class>Crusader_CLHomePage_Block</class>
            </crusaderhome>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

\app\code\local\Crusader\CLHomePage\Block\Qwerty.php

```
<?php
class Crusader_CLHomePage_Block_Qwerty extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    // Methods (optional)
}
?>
```

\app\design\frontend\crusader\default\layout\local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout>
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="homepage" template="crusader/home.phtml">
                <block type="crusaderhome/qwerty" name="homeads" as="homeads" template="crusader/homeads.phtml" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

\app\design\frontend\crusader\default\template\crusader\home.phtml

```
<div id="home">
<p>Home Wrapper</p>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('homeads'); ?>
</div>
```

\app\design\frontend\crusader\default\template\crusader\homeads.phtml

```
<p>Adverts</p>
```

Now, with the above in place, my home page shows just "Home Wrapper", so the content of `home.phtml` is displayed, but not the content of `homeads.phtml`.

If I change the block type for `homeads` to `core/template`, it works, and I see both "Home Wrapper" and "Adverts". So I know the problem is something to do with the reference to my new block type (called crusaderhome).

What am I doing wrong here..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer after posting on the Magento stack exchange site:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18098/magento-new-custom-block-module

It was the Magento compiler, once I disabled the compiler it seems to work.

Admin > System > Tools > Compilation

Answer (score 2):

First of all

change `\app\etc\modules\Crusader_All.xml` to

`\app\etc\modules\Crusader_CLHomePage.xml`

use `cLHomePage` (check the naming convention. You should use lowercase like `Clhomepage`) rather `crusaderhome` in block type.

in

```
<block type="crusaderhome/qwerty" name="homeads" as="homeads" template="crusader/homeads.phtml" />
```

Comment: Ok, so are you saying that I should call my block type (in config.xml) the same name as my module name (CLHomePage), but with only the first letter in caps..? I wasn't aware that the block type had to be called the same name as the module.

Comment: no no..not like that..`crusaderhome` its correct but you should check the naming convention..or can you paste the whole config file here

Comment: My original question shows the whole config file for the CLHomePage module. As far as I can see, the naming convention I'm using is correct for the block type name, all lowercase in both the config.xml file, and the block type attribute. I can't find examples of any other naming convention for this...

Comment: I changed Crusader_All.xml to Crusader_CLHomePage.xml... No effect, still doesn't work...

Comment: What..? What does that mean..?

Comment: @AmitBera its not the place to write that...if you can find the error please notify..help him