# Magento Invalid Block Type. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: magento

I've been on the IRC channel all day and have spent the past 4 hours trying to follow tutorials and paste code examples (and even rewrite them).

I just want to create a custom Module/Block, but no matter how much convention I follow, it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is a gist that contains the full details (and file pathnames) of my custom module:

https://gist.github.com/tatemz/304c8299a49d6b48736a

Can anyone figure this out?

Comment: Resolved by turning off Compilation.  Similar problem to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958701/magento-new-custom-block-module.

Comment: Thanks @MarcGuay! Solved it perfectly!